# Optimizing a large query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a long query with a structure like this -

```
with 
abc as (
              select ind, 
                     sum(count) as tot
                from LargeQuery
            group by ind),
xyz as (
              select org,
                     sum(count) as cnt
                from LargeQuery
            group by org
)
```

`LargeQuery` has a bunch of CTEs and sub queries. As you can see `LargeQuery` is being computed twice. Is there a way to optimize this query so it isn't run two times?

**UPDATE**

The format of my `largequery` is below. I do not think I can do `with largequery as (...), abc as (...), xyz as (...)` because `Org` and `Ind` are selected from this `largequery` and I need to use these in my `abc` and `xyz` cte's.

```
WITH cte
AS (

--bunch of queries

    )
SELECT org
    , ind
    , sum(count_final) AS count
FROM (
    SELECT org1 AS org
        , ind2 AS ind
        , count(*) AS count_final
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY org1
        , ind2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT org1 AS org
        , ind3 AS ind
        , count(*) AS count_final
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY org1
        , ind3
    ) x
GROUP BY org
    , ind;
```

Comment: `with largequery as (...), cte as (...), abc as (...)`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have updated my question as to why I think I cannot use the format you suggested. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: @Aaron we can refer to `largequery` from other cte like `with largequery as (blah), xyz as (select col1 from largequery), abc as (select col2 from largequery)`...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you want to do, but you can use `grouping sets`:

```
select ind, org, sum(count) as tot
from LargeQuery
group by grouping sets (ind, org);
```

This will do both aggregations at the same time.